# Передача по ссылке javascript

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo = {n: 2};
```

здесь `foo = {n: 2}, а bar = {n: 1}` и

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.n = 2;
```

здесь `foo = {n: 2} и bar = {n: 2}`

Comment: Ну, собственно, вы уже сами нашли в чем разница...

Comment: Не верно сформулировал вопрос. Хотел спросить почему так происходит. var foo = bar здесь ведь происходит передача по ссылке. Почему в первом случае foo и bar становятся разными объектами?

Comment: Нет в javascript никакой передачи по ссылке. Разными объектами они становятся потому что вы им присвоили разные объекты.

Comment: Хорошо, почему тогда во втором случае при изменении foo изменился bar?

Comment: Потому что это один и тот же объект.